# File corruption C with fputs and SED

Tags: c, sed, arm, fputs

I have a 'queue' (it's not quite FIFO) which is backed by files on the disk once it has run out of its preallocated memory. The built code is being executed on an ARM SBC.

**The problem** I'm having is that after a while the SD card (or a particular file on it?) where the buffer files are stored becomes corrupted and Linux then remounts it as read only. If I then insert the SD card into my Windows machine and run chkdsk on it it shows there are errors.

I'm using fopen, fputs, fclose and using a system call to SED that deletes a line from a file. Is there anything I'm doing wrong in the code? 
Should I replace my call system call to SED with my own function to rename the file, read it in, write it out again without the first line?

I've also tried another SD card as well.

Any pointers on how to investigate why the files are becoming corrupt would be very useful. - Thank you.

```
/// Number of elements in the in-memory section of the queue.
#define DISK_QUEUE_ELEMENTS 20
#define DISK_QUEUE_SIZE (DISK_QUEUE_ELEMENTS + 1)

/// Directory where the files will be stored that will buffer any messages when the queue exceeds DISK_QUEUE_ELEMENTS.
#define DISK_QUEUE_BUFF_DIR "/mnt/sd/buff/"

/// File name pattern for indexed buffer files.
#define DISK_QUEUE_FILE_PATTERN DISK_QUEUE_BUFF_DIR "buff%d.txt"
#define DISK_QUEUE_MSGS_PER_FILE 1000
#define DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN 32
#define DISK_QUEUE_SED_START "sed -i '1d' " 

/// This is the transmision message queue. This holds the in-memory messages.
struct TsqMessage DiskQueue[DISK_QUEUE_SIZE];
int DiskQueueIn;
int DiskQueueOut;

/// Mutex used for ensuring the disk queue functions are thread safe.
pthread_mutex_t dqLock;

/// A global to ensure that other parts of the system know how many messages there are on the disk, not in RAM.
int g_dqFileMessageCount;

/// Returns the number of lines in a file.
int GetLinesInBuffFile(char * file) {
    FILE* logfile = fopen(file, "r");
    if (logfile == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
        return 0;
    } else {
        int ch, number_of_lines = 0;
        do {
            ch = fgetc(logfile);
            if(ch == '\n') {
                number_of_lines++;
            }
        } while (ch != EOF);

        fclose(logfile);
        return number_of_lines;
    }
}

/// Returns the total number of messages that are buffered in files.
int GetLinesInBuffFiles() {
    int i = 0;
    char filename[DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN];
    int linesInCurrentFile = 0;
    int totalLinesInFiles = 0;
    do {
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN, DISK_QUEUE_FILE_PATTERN, i);
        ++i;
        linesInCurrentFile = GetLinesInBuffFile(filename);
        totalLinesInFiles += linesInCurrentFile;
    } while (linesInCurrentFile != 0);

    return totalLinesInFiles;
}

/// Initilaise the DiskQueue by setting the counters to 0 and getting the number of lines on the disk. It is reenterable.
void DiskQueueInit(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&dqLock);
    static char firstTime = 1;
    if (firstTime == 1) {
        mkdir(DISK_QUEUE_BUFF_DIR, 0777);
        DiskQueueIn = 0;
        DiskQueueOut = 0;
        g_dqFileMessageCount = GetLinesInBuffFiles();
        printf("Number of lines in buff files = %d\n", g_dqFileMessageCount);
    }
    firstTime = 2;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
}

/// Add a TsqMessage sruct to the DiskQueue.
int DiskQueuePut(struct TsqMessage newMsg) {

    int returnCode = 0;

    // Lock the DiskQueue before we do anything with it.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&dqLock);

    if (DiskQueueIn == (( DiskQueueOut - 1 + DISK_QUEUE_SIZE) % DISK_QUEUE_SIZE)) {

        // The in-memory DiskQueue is full so now we must store on the disk.
        char messageString[DISK_LINE_SIZE];

        //// TODO is this needed? memset(messageString, '\0', DISK_LINE_SIZE); // clear string

        // Convert message struct to string
        sprintf(messageString, "%d,%d,%f,%lld\n", newMsg.Source, newMsg.MessageId, newMsg.Value, newMsg.Timestamp);

        // append string to file
        char filename[DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN];
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN, DISK_QUEUE_FILE_PATTERN, g_dqFileMessageCount / DISK_QUEUE_MSGS_PER_FILE);

        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "a+");

        if (fp != NULL) {

            // Write string to file.
            if (fputs(messageString, fp) == EOF) {
                // Error
                printf("disk queue - fputs error\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
                exit(1);
            }

            // Close the file.
            if (fclose(fp) != EOF) {
                // if ok then g_dqFileMessageCount++ (so we know how many messages are in the files)
                g_dqFileMessageCount++;
                returnCode = 0;
            } else {
                // else log failure and return -1
                printf("Disk queue - error closing file (%s)\n", filename);
                returnCode = -1;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Disk queue - cannot open file (%s) - data lost.", filename);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
        return returnCode;
    } // else if in-memory queue not full then add to in-memory queue

    DiskQueue[DiskQueueIn] = newMsg;
    DiskQueueIn = (DiskQueueIn + 1) % DISK_QUEUE_SIZE;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
    return returnCode; // No errors
}

/// Pop the oldest TsqMessage struct of the in-memory DiskQueue if the disk is empty else pop it off of the disk file.
int DiskQueueGet(struct TsqMessage *old) {

    // Lock the DiskQueue before we do anything with it.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&dqLock);

    // If g_dqFileMessageCount is > 0 then prioritise getting messages off of the disk.
    if (g_dqFileMessageCount > 0) {
        char filename[DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN];
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * DISK_QUEUE_FILEPATH_LEN, DISK_QUEUE_FILE_PATTERN, (g_dqFileMessageCount-1) / DISK_QUEUE_MSGS_PER_FILE);

        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;

        // Open file
        FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        //printf("reading from file: %s\n", filename);
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR reading from disk buffer, no such file: %s\n", filename);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
            return -1;
        }

        // Read line from file
        if ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
            char* token;
            char* toFree;
            if (line != NULL) {
                toFree = line;
                int lineCounter = 0;
                while ((token = strsep(&line, ",")) != NULL) {
                    if (lineCounter == 0) {
                        old->Source = atoi(token); 
                    } else if (lineCounter == 1) {
                        old->MessageId = atoi(token);
                    } else if (lineCounter == 2 ) {
                        old->Value = atof(token); 
                    } else if (lineCounter == 3) {
                        old->Timestamp = atoll(token);
                    } else {
                        fclose(fp);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
                        printf("ERROR reading from disk buffer, bad format data\n");

                        return -1;
                    }
                    lineCounter++;
                }
                free(toFree);
            }
        } else {
            int errsv = errno;
            fclose(fp);
            free(line);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
            printf("ERROR reading from disk buffer, messages that it thinks are on the disk:%d, errorcode:%d\n", g_dqFileMessageCount, errsv);
            return -1;
        }

        fclose(fp);
        free(line);

        // Delete line from file that we just read.
        char * sedCommand;
        asprintf(&sedCommand, "%s %s", DISK_QUEUE_SED_START, filename);
        int sedRet = system(sedCommand);
        free(sedCommand);
        if (sedRet != 0) {
            printf(" --- --- SED ERROR %d \n", sedRet); // TODO handle if possible?
        } else {
            g_dqFileMessageCount--;
        }

        // We've set *old to be the read value from the file so we can safely unlock and return.
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
        return 0;
    }

    // Queue empty
    if (DiskQueueIn == DiskQueueOut) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);
        return -1;
    }

    // Return the next item from the queue.
    *old = DiskQueue[DiskQueueOut];
    DiskQueueOut = (DiskQueueOut + 1) % DISK_QUEUE_SIZE;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dqLock);

    // No errors
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a corruption in the filesystem, it is not the code failing, but the underlying operating system, or the hardware.

Try using a new SD card. Also keep in mind that SD card have a limited number of write that can be performed before degrading, so try to find some kind of memory buffering to avoid exhausting it too quickly.

Comment: I was worried it may be the OS/hardware - something I do not have control over.
Thanks for the comments re SD card, I've tried new ones.

Comment: Maybe you can use a memory-based filesystem and periodically (say, once an hour) sync the content of the (now volatile) file to the sd card. I usually use subdir in the /dev/shm directory, which is RAM based on debian-like systems.

Comment: Ok thanks I was not aware of the /dev/shm directory. Yes ideally I'd just use RAM and then keep a shadow copy on the disk in case of power failure so  minimal data is lost, unfortunately the system doesn't have enough RAM to store the incoming data. Your suggestion of syncing periodically may be a good place to start, in that I could do one large write to disk less often. The only issue would be that there would be a large amount of data at risk of being lost in RAM but that would be better than the current situation!